# How to detect whether window is opened by js

Tags: javascript

I have a  user-config page in my settings page and the `user-config` page is opened by JS

```
<a onclick="window.open("@/@user-config.php", "User Config", "directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=350,height=450");">Open User Config Window</a>
```

It should not be opened directly,
     So, Is there a way to detect whether the window is opened by JS or Not

Thanks

Comment: Check if [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) exists from your `user-config.php`. If the page is opened directly you will not have window.opener

Comment: You could check if the popup has an `opener` set - but that would also be the case, if it was opened via a link with normal href + target="_blank" set. _"It should not be opened directly"_ - why not, what damage exactly would that cause?

Comment: I don't want to be "that guy", but users will do what users do. Why not make it possible to open it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the best thing would be to allow the page to be opened directly. Users will do what users do.

But if you don't want to do that (or can't for some reason), the first thing that comes to mind is to have the JavaScript open a window without a URL (for instance, `about:blank`) and then populate that window with the result of doing an ajax call with a header that won't be set on a direct request (unless someone does a direct request with Postman or something, and worrying about that is probably overkill). The PHP can check for the header. That looks something like this:

```
function openUserConfig() {
    const win = window.open("about:blank", "User Config", "directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=350,height=450");
    win.document.write("<em>Loading...</em>");
    win.document.close();
    fetch("@/@user-config.php", {
        headers: {
            "The-Header": "Header Value",
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(html => {
        win.document.write(html);
        win.document.close();
    })
    .catch(() => {
        win.document.write("<strong>Error loading user config</strong>"); // Or whatever
        win.document.close();
    });
}
```

Combined with the PHP to check for the header and send back (for instance) a [403 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) if it's not there.

Note that the document markup returned by `@/@user-config.php` will also need a [`base` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base?retiredLocale=id) so that relative URLs in the page (for CSS, JavaScript, fonts; links in the text) resolve correctly. (Or make all the URLs in the page absolute, or inline everything.)

---

But again, I'd go with making it something you can directly open if possible.

Comment: I have a problem that the linked CSS in `@user-config.php`, Is not working

Comment: @N_R01 - Yes, this would require either absolute URLs for those things, or a [`base` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base?retiredLocale=id) (or that it all be inlined).

Comment: @N_R01 - Yes, I understood the problem, see the comment above.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was fixed in another way, I used `<?=$location?>../../../../c8kj48/css/cp-main.css` in PHP, thanks, :)